# If $ G$ is an almost simple finite group, then $G$ has no nontrivial normal abelian Sylow subgroup

Tags: finite-groups, simple-groups

Why the almost simple finite groups has no nontrivial normal abelian Sylow subgroups?
Any illustrations or recommended books to understand this idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S\lhd G$ be the non-abelian simple group, and let $P\lhd G$ be a normal Sylow subgroup. Note that $S\cap P\lhd S$, so $S\cap P=1$.  Thus $P$ centralizes $S$, which means it acts trivially on $S$.  Since $G$ is almost simple, $P$ is trivial.

Note that $P$ being abelian doesn't matter here.  What's important is that $P$ cannot contain a non-abelian simple subgroup (so that $S\cap P\neq S$).  Thus, the same argument shows $G$ contains no normal solvable subgroup.